# during copy transform constraint, the child object snaps to the origin point of the parent object

Tags: animation, constraints

When i use the copy transformation constraint, the child object snaps to the origin point of the parent object.

What i want is, when i constraint an object, the child object should remain where it is, but when i move the parent object, the child should move with it, maintaining the distance and the rotation offset between them.

Comment: Then why do you use constraints? copy location does exactly that: move the object to the exact same location. Just use parenting, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Frederik Steinmetz: because a simple Copy Location won't copy the other transforms like rotation and scale.

Comment: "when i move the parent object, the child should move with it, maintaining the distance and the rotation offset between them."  Sounds like what you want is a child-of constraint, if the target is unparented and not otherwise constrained; otherwise, you want to copy transforms of an unparented empty with same orientation and a child-of.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the *Copy Transforms* doesn't have any *Offset* option (I don't know why), so I guess if you want it to copy each of its target's transformation you need instead to give it a *Copy Location* constraint (enable the *Offset* option), a *Copy Rotation* and a *Copy Scale*.